# How to configure LoggingMeterRegistry step duration in Spring Boot 2.x?

Tags: spring-boot, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I am trying to configure the LoggingMeterRegistry to log metrics for my Spring Boot 2.1.6 application. I want the metrics to be logged every hour.

In my application.yml, I've the following configured

```
management:
  metrics:
    export:
      logging:
        enabled: true
        step: 60m
```

But in the logs I see the metrics being logged every minute. I've tried the other variation for the property key as well e.g.

```
management.metrics.export.logging:
  enabled: true
  step: 60m
```

I have also tried various formats for the duration string e.g. `1h`, `PT60M` but with no success. The metrics are logged at 1 minute intervals.

I was looking at the code here [StepDurationConverterTest](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-spring-legacy/src/test/java/io/micrometer/spring/autoconfigure/export/StringToDurationConverterTest.java) and here [StepDurationConverter](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-spring-legacy/src/main/java/io/micrometer/spring/autoconfigure/export/StringToDurationConverter.java) that converts the step duration String to a Duration object and looks like both formats `60m` and `1h` should work.

Any ideas why I can't seem to change the logging interval?

Comment: That step should work. Have you tried putting a break point in `LoggingMeterRegistry` to see if it is reading in your property?

Answer (score 4):

The following `@Bean` supplies config from Spring `Environment` allowing you to specify a property `logging.step: 1h` to get your desired period.

```java
    @Bean
    LoggingMeterRegistry loggingMeterRegistry(Environment env) {
        LoggingRegistryConfig springBasedConfig = prop -> env.getProperty(prop, String.class);
        return new LoggingMeterRegistry(springBasedConfig, Clock.SYSTEM);
    }
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It just works and also supports application.yaml properties (but not step, for some reason)

Comment: This indeed is the way around this problem...

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem here is there's no 
`org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.export.logging` 
package like there is for other `MeterRegistry`s (eg `org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.export.jmx`).

Ie theres no auto configuration for the properties in Spring Boot. This is probably because the `LoggingMeterRegistry` is marked as `@Incubating`

You need to manually configure the `LoggingMeterRegistry` as a bean and create your own `@ConfigurationProperties` `LoggingProperties` and `LoggingPropertiesConfigAdapter` to get this to work. Or just hardcode the step period you want.

Answer (score 0):

To configure step count duration in micrometer:
Please follow below step:

```
@Configuration
public class LoggingMeterRegistryConfig {
    @Bean
    public LoggingMeterRegistry loggingMeterRegistry() {

        LoggingRegistryConfig config = new LoggingRegistryConfig() {

            @Override
            public String get(String s) {

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Duration step() {

                return Duration.ofMinutes(2);
            }
        };
        return LoggingMeterRegistry.builder(config).clock(Clock.SYSTEM).threadFactory(new NamedThreadFactory("logging-metrics-publisher")).build();
    }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I want to share a solution of mine which I posted at https://stackoverflow.com/a/76884882/418599 .

```java
@Bean
LoggingMeterRegistry loggingMeterRegistry(Environment environments) {
    LoggingRegistryConfig config =
        key -> {
            String property = null;

            switch (key) {
                case "logging.enabled":
                    property = "management.metrics.export.logging.enabled";
                    break;

                case "logging.step":
                    property = "management.metrics.export.logging.step";
                    break;

            }

            return
                  (null != property)
                ? environments.getProperty(property)
                : null;
        };

    return new LoggingMeterRegistry(config, Clock.SYSTEM);
}
```

**application.yaml**

```yaml
management:
  metrics:
    export:
      logging:
        step: 10s
```