# MicroMeter LoggingMeterRegistry configuration in SpringBoot 3 application

Tags: java, spring-boot, metrics, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I am writing a SpringBoot 3 application which needs to report metrics inside log files too.

I registered an instance of `io.micrometer.core.instrument.logging.LoggingMeterRegistry` by:

```java
@Bean
LoggingMeterRegistry loggingMeterRegistry() {
    return new LoggingMeterRegistry();
}
```

It works as expected, but:

1. I don't know how to provide configuration settings (like the `step`) by the `application.yaml` file.
2. I don't know how to register a custom instance of the class `com.codahale.metrics.MetricFilter` to filter the output.

Could somebody tell me how to achieve these goals?

Thank you so much in advance!

**Edit:** my issue seems similar to [How to configure LoggingMeterRegistry step duration in Spring Boot 2.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57663369/how-to-configure-loggingmeterregistry-step-duration-in-spring-boot-2-x) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my very clean workaround for the first question **"I don't know how to provide configuration settings (like the step) by the application.yaml file"** (found after a lot of debugging of `LoggingMeterRegistry`).

**Configuration class**

```java
@Bean
LoggingMeterRegistry loggingMeterRegistry(Environment environments) {
    LoggingRegistryConfig config =
        key -> {
            String property = null;

            switch (key) {
                case "logging.enabled":
                    property = "management.metrics.export.logging.enabled";
                    break;

                case "logging.step":
                    property = "management.metrics.export.logging.step";
                    break;

            }

            return
                  (null != property)
                ? environments.getProperty(property)
                : null;
        };

    return new LoggingMeterRegistry(config, Clock.SYSTEM);
}
```

**application.yaml**

```yaml
management:
  metrics:
    export:
      logging:
        step: 10s
```

Now, I am going to find a solution for the second issue...